# PHP delay  redirect back to a page

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to timely redirect back a user to **the page from where he entered the page** ?

if he entered the page from `1.php`  to ----> `2.php` i need a delay redirect to `1.php`

> redirect always to the page where he
>   entered the other page

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you can redirect a web visitor with simple HTTP headers, for example `header("Location: $newURL") ;`

Comment: are you trying to redirect user to page where he logged in ?

Comment: redirect always to the page where he entered the other page

Comment: So the user would be redirected to 1.php after n seconds of viewing 2.php?

Comment: like this `2.php` can be accessed by multiple pages but i want to redirect back to that pages with a relay

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a meta tag:

```
<?php if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { ?>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Otherwise, you can use a JavaScript solution:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("window.location = '<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>'", 2000);
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Good that you added `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Comment: If you're using either of these solutions, you should add a text link on the page you are redirecting _from_, so that if meta/JavaScript don't work, at least your users have something to see/click on.

Answer (score 3):

PHP isn't dynamic (and not clientside) so you can't make timers. You'll have to use a meta tag or JavaScript. See this answer: [Redirect with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091729/redirect-with-php/6091735#6091760).

Answer (score 1):

If they got through by entering data in a form, then pass the page1 address back to page2 in a hidden field.

page1.php -> puts out a form

```
<form action = page2.php method=post>
<input type=hidden name=return value=page1 />
<input type = submit />
</form>
```

page2.php -> handles the form, detects where to return the user

```
$next = 'default-welcome-page';
$permitted = array('page1','page3','page4');
if( isset($_POST['return'])
&& in_array($_POST['return'], $permitted) ){
$next = $_POST['return'];
}
header(Location: $next.'php');
exit;
```

Otherwise you could construct a html link, and do the same as above but using the $_GET array instead of $_POST

```
<a href=page.php?return=page1>Go on, go on...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but perhaps useful nonetheless:

```
header ("Refresh:5; URL=proceed.php");
```

Just make sure to play by the rules, header must come first before anything.